# Explain the call stack of this function?

Tags: python, recursion

I have the code:

```
def recursion0(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        recursion0(x-1)
        print x
```

I know values 2-x will print, but I cannot figure out how to map the call stack. Below are my thoughts.

Let's set x = 3.  3 goes to 2 in recursion0(3-1), and then 2 goes to 1 in recursion0(2-1).  Is 1 then returned to the function that called it, recursion0(2-1), and then 2 is printed because it is the x value?  What happens after this so 3 is printed? 
Another question, why does x print after 1 is returned (and not before)?

Comment: "Where is the value of the previous function returned" - it's not. Should it be?

Comment: 1 is returned from `recursion0(1)` to `recursion0(2)` (or whoever is calling it).

Comment: Then is 2 returned to recursion0(3), and if so, what is making it (2) return when there is no "return" statement?

Comment: `2` is NOT returned to `recursion0(3)`. See my answer, I have explained it there in the first 3 lines.

Comment: Nothing is returned because there are no return statements, except for 1 which is the value given to recursion0(2).  Then 2 is printed because x = 2. I still don't know what happens after this so 3 is printed.

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `recursion0(3)` will not return `1`, but `None`, because your else path doesn't return anything.

To fix it, change `recursion0(x-1)` to `return recursion0(x-1)`.

As your `print` comes after the recursion, the printing order is the opposite of the calling order.

---

> I want values from 1-x printed, and how does this process work?

```
def recursion0(x):
    if x == 0: return
    recursion0(x-1)
    print (x)

recursion0(3)
```

Output is:

```
>>> 
1
2
3
```